# Get the output dir created by the Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am working on a process wherein we need to get the output dir created by the Makefile. The output dir will then be used by the shell script.

If anyone has worked on this kind of approach then please let me know the ideal way.

Comment: There's no one way to do it.  Probably the simplest thing to do would be for the "shell script" to choose the output dir pathname on its own, then tell make what it is, like `make OUTPUT_DIR="$myoutputdir"` then you don't need to make to tell the script what it was.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for the confirmation. That's what I thought. Would it make sense to output the dir created by the make target and in some way parse it ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "make sense".  It would work, if that's what you mean, assuming you could get the parsing right and it was reliable.  This is all just opinion and conjecture, and StackOverflow is not really about that.  It's about asking concrete questions with concrete answers, not "what's the best way to do XYZ".  The best way is for the script to compute the output path and tell the makefile about it.  If you really have to have the makefile compute the output path and tell the script about it, there are lots of ways to do it, with their own advantages and disadvantages.